# ViewModelProviders is not working inside my Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, fragment, android-viewmodel

This is what I'm trying to do.

- Set an `ArrayList` of object inside a Fragment
- Get that array from an    observer within the `FragmentActivity`
  container (the activity that    hosts all the fragments)

So, What I have done is the following.

First I created the `SharedViewModel` from where I will set and get the data from :

### SharedViewModel.kt

```
class SharedViewModel: ViewModel() {

    var personArrayObj:MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Person>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun setPersonArray(personArray:ArrayList<Person>){
        personArrayObj.value = personArray
    }

    val getPersonArray:LiveData<ArrayList<Person>>
    get() = personArrayObj

}
```

Now , I instantiate this `ViewModel` inside the `MainActivity` that hosts all the fragments creation, so , I can get the `ArrayData` from wherever Fragment its set :

### MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity: FragmentActivity(){

private lateinit var viewModel:SharedViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.getPersonArray.observe(this, Observer { it:ArrayList<Person>
            Log.d("Array:",""+it)
        })
    }

}
```

Then the last thing I need to do is to set the value of that Array from whatever Fragment I want, and then the host Activity will be triggered if the value has changed, so, to do this, I simple do a `viewModel.setValue(personArray)` at my desired **Fragment** .

### The Problem

When I try to instantiate the `SharedViewModel` inside any fragment I get this problem :

[image]

I tried to assert !! for the null, use let too, but is not working and I wonder from where it comes that `FragmentActivity` required

If I use `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `activity` it says to me that it cant be called either with **Fragment** or **FragmentActivity** ?

Any clues?

Thanks .

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fragments offer a helper method for retrieving a non-null Activity - `requireActivity()`. Use that instead of `activity`:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
```

As an alternative, you can include the `fragment-ktx` dependency in your app and use the [by activityViewModels()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#activityviewmodels) Kotlin property extension instead of using `ViewModelProviders.of()` at all:

```
val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: Using `requireActivity()` is more or less equivalent of using `activity!!`. The app will crash. Either on `IllegalStateException` or a NPE.

Comment: @MarošŠeleng - from a lifecycle method such as `onViewCreated()` as it is in this case, it'll never crash, so whether you suppress the lint warning, use `!!` or use `requireActivity()` you'll get the same runtime behavior for all three.

Comment: That's true, but you do not mention any of that in your answer, which, *in general*, makes it a bad practice. I think we all know, how big hell can Fragment's lifecycle be, so why not write it safe all the time?

Comment: @MarošŠeleng - `requireActivity()` is absolutely safe in `onViewCreated()` and that is why my answer points it out as the correct way of getting a non-null activity instance when you, as a developer, **can guarantee** the activity must be non-null.

Comment: Also, you can call `this` inside that method:
`viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)` inside fragment, `this` is pointer to `owner`.

Comment: @Stanojkovic - that does something totally different by creating a ViewModel scoped to that individual fragment and **not** scoped to the entire Activity as passing `requireActivity()` as the owner does.

Answer (score 3):

ViewModelProviders.of() is deprecated.So,we can initialize viewmodel like below.

```
 viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SampleViewModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was not seeing it

I was making an instance of the `viewModel` inside my **Fragment**, and another one, inside my **MainActivity**, so doing this, we prevent the observer to work.

To solve this, I just made a simple method that returns the instance that I made inside my `MainActivity`

```
 fun getViewModelInstance():SharedViewModel = viewModel
```

Then I just call that instance from any Fragment to work with it

```
(activity as MainActivity).getViewModelInstance().setPersonArray(personArray)
```

Comment: When you use `ViewModelProvider.of()` and pass in your activity, you are going to get the exact same instance back that was in the Activity, so you had the right idea. It is only if you pass in `this` from within the Fragment that you create a brand new ViewModel tied to the Fragment.

Comment: You don't want to do that, if you want to use the same one as in the activity, just use the activity scope.

Comment: Very helpful. Was stuck here as well. Thank you geeks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, issue is that inside your fragment class **activity context** would be **nullable** and `ViewModelPorviders` require **Non-null context** to work with.

One solution would be making your `ViewModel` object **nullable** *(because your activity is nullable)* inside your fragment like something below:

```
var viewModel: SharedViewModel? = null
```

then during initialization,

```
viewModel = activity?.let { ViewModelProviders.of(it).get(SharedViewModel::class.java) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the thing in onActivityCreated() instead of onCreateView()...
That will solve the issue of getActivity() nullable...
Because according to the lifecycle of a fragment, onActivityCreated() is after onCreareView()...
And the activity is created on the call of onActivityCreated()...
So, the getActivity() will return the activity just created