# What is the difference between passing"this" and "activity!!" as a ViewModelStoreOwner while creating ViewModelProvider instance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-viewmodel, viewmodelproviders

Hi I am a Kotlin learner, wanted to understand the difference between passing"this" and "activity!!" as a ViewModelStoreOwner while creating ViewModelProvider instance in a fragment for ex

```
 viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        InventoryDetailsFragmentViewModelFactory.getInstance(activity!!.application)
    )
        .get(InventoryDetailsFragmentViewModel::class.java)
```

when I am using this as owner sometimes observer is not working
Please help me to understand difference in using this and activity!!

Comment: Where does this code appear? Is it in a fragment?

Comment: Please read the bottom half of the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61974340/2235972

Comment: yes @CommonsWare

Answer (score 2):

You are able to pass either `this` (a `Fragment`) or `activity!!` (a `FragmentActivity`) to the `ViewModelProvider` constructor because both implement [the `ViewModelStoreOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStoreOwner) interface.

The role of a `ViewModelStoreOwner` is to be able to provide a `ViewModelStore`, when needed, where the `ViewModelStore` represents a collection of existing viewmodels:

- If you use `this` and pass a `Fragment` to the `ViewModelProvider` constructor, the `ViewModelStore` will be tied to that `Fragment`. This fragment and child fragments might share viewmodels, but those viewmodels should not be shared with other peer fragments or parents.
- If you use `activity!!` and pass a `FragmentActivity` to the `ViewModelProvider` constructor, the `ViewModelStore` will be tied to that `FragmentActivity`. Not only can this activity use the viewmodel, but any fragments used in that activity could also share that viewmodel.

You need to decide what the proper scope is of your `InventoryDetailsFragmentViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

> "this" means "Context", which is the Fragment you are Instantiated the viewModel.
>
> From the code you provided i can understand "this" = "InventoryDetailsFragment", which is >the class you instantiated the viewModel.
>
> Your code should look like this

```
val application = requireNotNull(activity).application
viewModelFactory = InventoryDetailsFragmentViewModelFactory(application)
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
            .get(InventoryDetailsFragmentViewModel::class.java)
```

> If you want to see an example where ViewModel and ViewModelFactory are used in a project visit this link [sample](https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-mars-real-estate/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/marsrealestate/detail)

Comment: ""this" means "Context", which is the Fragment you are Instantiated the viewModel" -- a fragment is not a `Context`.