# Android: Different ViewModel instance for different Navigation Graph java/kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-navigation

I am using Android navigation component, and I have a fragment, FragA, that is being reused in multiple navigation graph, I want to have different instances of ViewModel for this fragA in each graph.
I looked around and found `by navGraphViewModels(R.id.child_graph)` however this requires to know which graph I am coming from, but I don't know it since FragA is being reused.

I can't pass graph in arguments/bundle since doing something like `private val childGraphScopedViewModel: ChildGraphScopedViewModel by navGraphViewModels(arguments.getInt) {` won't work, because arguments is still Null when that line of code is being called.

So my question is how can make the graph id dynamic?
Do I have to write my custom implementation that mirrors `by navGraphViewModels`?
(Also I may need such a thing to work in java/kotlin)

Comment: do you want `different instances of ViewModel` of the same class or different classes?

Comment: @denvercoder9 different instance of same ViewModelA for a same FragA that is opened in 2 different Navigation Graph

Comment: use `by viewModels()` instead of `by navGraphViewModels(..)`. Please read this answer and the comments as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/61974340/2235972 That might explain some stuff. Also, read the docs on `viewModels()` and `navGraphViewModels()`

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you to use SubFrag1, SubFrag2 ... of FragA for each graph.

```
open class FragA

class SubFrag1: FragA()

class SubFrag2: FragA()
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping I can avoid extending the class, will definitely keep it in mind

Comment: I can't see other solutions because viewmodel created in any fragment will exist and reused until it's destruction.